# Modifying the Announcement Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, announcements

Our company uses an Announcements lists in SharePoint Online to act as a bulletin board; all users have the permissions to add their own new announcements. The system is working fine except for one little annoyance:

-The user clicks the announcement Title
-It opens in a new window
-The window that opens displays the Content Type, Title, Body, Start Date, End Date, and Attachments

We would like a see the "Created By" in this view of the announcement. I have tried to add the column to the Announcement content type, but it is not included in the list of available columns.

Here is the Bulletin Board:

[image]

This is what you see when you open the announcement (no Created By):

[image]

Comment: could you share an image for the display page! Is it custom? by default, It should has the *created by* and *created date*!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, it is not a Created By column or Created column in modern list form page.

As a workaround, we can go to list settings, and modify the list view add this column in the view, then we can see the created by column in the UI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this isn't the issue. The Created By column has already been added to the list view. The problem occurs when you click the Title to open the announcement. I have added screenshots to my original post to demonstrate.

Comment: It is by design in the modern list form page. we can't modify it currently.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the solution is to go to List Settings > Advanced Settings and set the List experience to "Classic experience." Now the Created By information shows up in the Announcement.

Comment: Yes, by design the Created By field in Classic list form.